# Why is my shiny app not restarting when I make changes?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to run the file `shiny.Rmd` on the command line using the following command:

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::run('shiny.Rmd')"
```

But when I edit my code, the changes are not reflected on the local host page that is generated. There must be some way to restart the server but I cannot find an answer that works for the command line (I have seen other similar questions asked but I cannot see how to apply the answer to my case).

A minimal example of `Shiny.Rmd` could be:

````
---
title: "Multiple Pages"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---
```{r setup}
library(shiny)
library('scales')
```
Page 1
=====================================


```{r}
```


```{r}
```

Page 2
=====================================

### Chart 1

```{r}
```
````

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of a `shiny.Rmd` file that you are testing with? How exactly are you editing/saving the source files? Are you refreshing in the browser as well?

Comment: I tend to use `sudo systemctl restart shiny-server`

Comment: @RyanMorton any idea what the command would be on MacOs?

Comment: I wasn't aware that MacOS was supported for shiny-server.

Comment: @MrFlick I do refresh the browser, but generally I just make a change to the .rmd file. (could be as trivial as adding a print('hi) to one of the `r` fields.) and then run the `rmarkdown::run` command again and when I re-navigate to the local host page, it is still the same file that I ran days ago the very first time I used the `rmarkdown:: run` command. It's stuck on that one file.

Comment: @RyanMorton ah okay perhaps I am just not able to run that command. I am not really able to find a suitable command that works on Mac for restarting my shiny server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a work-around. When I altered my command to

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::run('tester.Rmd', default_file='tester.Rmd', shiny_args=list(port=8241))"
```

it now seems to be updating again.